# Exclude a specific file or file type from fortify scan

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

How to exclude a specific file or file type (like config or xml) from fortify scan.

Appreciated your response.

Regards
Abdul

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**" parameter to do recursion into subdirectories. So use:

```
 -exclude "**\*.xml"
```

in your translation phase, for example:

```
sourceanalyzer -b BUILDID ./ -exclude "**\*.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks @Alesanco - let me check.